# How to add context to the word in CakePhp i18n?

Tags: cakephp, internationalization

I am using Cakephp internationalization and want to give context to the word.
Messages are written in English as default language in application.
Some (bold) messages comes from database.
For example:

Original: Evaluation of **first** grade of **first** part of **first** level ...

Translated: Hodnotenie **prvého** ročníka, **prvej** časti, **prvého** stupňa ...

In some languages, word has different form in use with different words. For example, there can be 10 different forms of one word. How can I tell cakephp application to show correct form of word "first" which come from database?

Comment: What is the grammatical difference between *prvého* and *prvej*? What kind of context information does that require?

Comment: Also, is "first" dynamic? I.e. do you want to dynamically generate 1 → "first", 2 → "second" etc? That gets pretty tricky with just English alone, not to mention grammatical differences such as you mention. The easy choice in this case is to avoid ordinals and output "Evaluation of grade 1 of part 1 of level 1..." instead. Else you'll have to write a lot of code. :)

Comment: Grammatical difference is that _prvého_ is form for male gender, genitive, singular. _prvej_ is form for woman gender, genitive, singular. Yes, in Slovak language, things can have own gender.

Ordinals are required. I cant replace them with numbers

Answer (score 2):

Some time after the question, the `__x()` function was added. It's intended precisely for adding context into i18n literals.

General help:
https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/internationalization-and-localization.html#using-translation-functions

Migration guide:
https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/appendices/2-6-migration-guide.html#basics-php

API info for CakePHP 3:
https://api.cakephp.org/3.4/function-__x.html

API info for CakePHP 2:
https://api.cakephp.org/2.9/function-__x.html

Answer (score 0):

CakePHP (at least 1.3 does) offers the __d() function. It's used as:

```
__d($domain, $message, $return)
```

Where you could use 'domain' to specify the grammatical significance of the word you want to translate. When done writing code you'd run CakePHP's i18n console task. This will create multiple .pot files in APP/locale/ which will be named .pot. Filename will be $domain, so you'd get a .pot file for each of the grammatical significances (really, I don't know an appropriate word for this) you've defined.

CakePHP's i18n console task searches your app's files for the translation function and then places the strings to be translated in a file, at least I think that's the way it works. If the content you want to translate is dynamic (which it is in your case) the console task won't be able to find your strings, which means you'll have to build your .pot files yourself. If **all** your content that needs translation is dynamic, you may want to make one file which contains the translation function once for each grammatical significance and then run the console task so you'll at least have the appropriate files.

A generated .pot file will contain the following three lines once for string that needs translating (unless that string is used multiple times, in that case it will have one occurence, only the first line will be repeated (slightly different) for each occurence).

```
#: /app_controller.php:129
msgid "Home"
msgstr ""
```

The line with the hashtag in front of it is just for your reference (to see where the string occurred), you wouldn't need to add it if you were building the file yourself. 'msgid' is the word/senctence you want to translate and 'msgstr' is the provided translation.
Building the files yourself consists of just copying these three lines over and over and changing the msgid and entering something as translation. I think the easiest way of building these files is building one file first and then copying the content (as the msgid will be the same for all of these files) and then entering the appropriate translations.

After you're done, move your .pot files to APP/locale//LC_MESSAGES/ and change their extension to .po.

This method obviously only works if there's only a fixed number of words you want to translate, because the translation functions depend on you hardcoding the translations in the .po files before they are needed. So if you're translating user input this probably won't be the ideal solution.

Sources:

- Own experience with CakePHP's i18n functionality
- [CakePHP Book on Internationalization](http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/en/view/1229/Internationalizing-Your-Application)
- Example is copied from one of the .pot files in the app i'm working on.

Comment: So, it means I need to have separate .po files for each form of the word? I am looking for something such elegant as plural forms are.

Comment: Indeed, you'd need a file for each form of the word (though of course, each file would contain multiple words). Though I now realize that with male/female, plural/singular and multiple grammatical cases this can amount to quite a lot of files.

Comment: In that case, I'd suggest using an adaptation of my above answer using either [__n()](http://api.cakephp.org/file/cake/basics.php#function-__n) or [__dn()](http://api.cakephp.org/file/cake/basics.php#function-__dn)

These functions are similar in use, only I have no experience using them. The Book (for 1.3) sadly doesn't explain them.
You might have to do some research into their workings yourself, but these function should have support for single/plural with multiple counts as (quote) "Some languages have more than one form for plural messages dependent on the count."

Comment: Clarification of above comment: You could 'misuse' the $count parameter for defining the grammatical cases. To make programming easier you could map certain count integer's to their grammatical cases in a bootstrap array so you don't need to remember the correct integers but can in stead use a string like MaleGenitSin for Male Genitiv Singular.

If this looks more promising I could do some more research and update my above answer. Just let me know..